# Problems with AS3 scrollbar script

Tags: actionscript-3, user-interface

I have this symbol for a scrollbar in adobe flash:
[image: scrollbar symbol]
The instance name of the dark part is `handle`, and that of the lighter bar is `bar`. The symbol is an instance of the `Scroll` class:

```
package ui {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    
    public class Scroll extends MovieClip{
        public static const VERTICAL = 0; 
        public static const HORIZONTAL = 1;
        protected var _handleRatio = 1;
        protected var _orientation = VERTICAL;
        protected var _mousePrevPos:int;
        protected var _handleMargin:int;
        protected var _container:MovieClip;
        protected var _containerInitialPosition:int; //added after update #2

        public function Scroll(container:MovieClip, visibleLength:int, orientation:int = VERTICAL) {
            _orientation = orientation;
            _container = container;
            
            var containerLength:int;
            switch(_orientation){
                case VERTICAL:
                    rotation = 0;
                    containerLength = container.height;
                    _containerInitialPosition = container.y; //added after update #2
                    break
                
                case HORIZONTAL:
                    rotation = - 90;
                    containerLength = container.width;
                    _containerInitialPosition = container.x; //added after update #2
                    break;
                
                default:
                    throw new Error('Unknown orientation');
                    break;
            }
            
            if((_handleRatio = visibleLength/containerLength) > 1)
                _handleRatio = 1;
            
            handle.height = _handleRatio*height;
            
            _handleMargin = handle.y;
            
            handle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, _startDrag, false, 0, true);
        }
        
        protected function _startDrag(e:MouseEvent){
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _stopDrag, false, 0, true);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, _dragHandle, false, 0, true);
            _mousePrevPos = mouseY;
        }
        
        protected function _stopDrag(e:MouseEvent = null){
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _stopDrag);
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, _dragHandle);
            _mousePrevPos = NaN;
        }
        
        protected function _dragHandle(e:MouseEvent){
            _moveHandle(mouseY - _mousePrevPos);
            _mousePrevPos = mouseY;
        }
        
        protected function _moveHandle(moveDifference:int){
            if(moveDifference > 0 && !(handle.y + handle.height + _handleMargin > bar.height)){
                if(!(handle.y + handle.height + moveDifference + _handleMargin > bar.height))
                    handle.y = handle.y + moveDifference;
                else
                    handle.y = bar.height - handle.height - _handleMargin;
            }
            
            if(moveDifference < 0 && !(handle.y < _handleMargin)){
                if(!(handle.y + moveDifference < _handleMargin))
                    handle.y += moveDifference;
                else
                    handle.y = _handleMargin;
            }
            
            switch(_orientation){
                case VERTICAL:
                    _container.y = _containerInitialPosition -((handle.y-_handleMargin)/(bar.height-_handleMargin*2)*_container.height);
                    // since update #2, the calculated y position is subtracted from the initial y position
                    break
                
                case HORIZONTAL:
                    _container.x = _containerInitialPosition -((handle.y-_handleMargin)/(bar.height-_handleMargin*2)*_container.width);
                    // since update #2, the calculated x position is subtracted from the initial x position
                    break;
                
                default:
                    throw new Error('Unknown orientation');
                    break;
            }
        }
        
        public function resize(newWidth, newHeight){
            switch(_orientation){
                case VERTICAL:
                    width = newWidth;
                    height = newHeight;
                    break
                
                case HORIZONTAL:
                    rotation = 0;
                    width = newHeight;
                    height = newWidth;
                    rotation = -90;
                    break;
                
                default:
                    throw new Error('Unknown orientation');
                    break;
            }
        }
        
        public function scrollHandle(e:MouseEvent){
            _moveHandle(-e.delta);
        }
    }
    
}
```

As you can see, you can create both horizontal and vertical scrollbars. Now, there are two problems with the scrollbar:

1. For some reason, when dragging the handle up/left with the mouse, the handle moves far slower than the cursor
2. <strike>Also, when you scroll a horizontal scrollbar a little to the right, the left part of the container is cut off, and you can't scroll back to it anymore</strike> solved now, see update #2

I really don't know what causes these problems, so can anyone please help me or at least point out where the errors in my code are?

### Update

Some extra information to help explain the code:

[image]
This is a sketch of a situation where a vertical scrollbar would be needed. The scrollbar would be initiated like so:

```
var scrollBar:Scroll = new Scroll(container, mask.height, Scroll.VERTICAL);
```

When the handle of the scrollbar is dragged/scrolled down, the container is moved upwards, so that you get to see a lower part of the contaienr - and vice versa: if you scroll up, the container is moved down.

If you'd want to create a horizontal scrollbar, apart from changing `Scroll.VERTICAL` into `Scroll.HORIZONTAL`, you'd pass `mask.width` as `visibleLength` instead of `mask.height`.

I suppose `container` doesn't neccessarily have to be a `MovieClip` but can be any `DisplayObject`.

Also, I'm not using `startDrag()` so that I can drag the handle and scroll the handle up and down with just one method (`_moveHandle()`).

### Update #2

I solved problem #2: the left part of the container was cut off because when the container hadn't been scrolled yet, the container's `x` position was somewhere in the middle of the stage. When it was scrolled a little bit to the right, I forgot to set the container's `x` position to the calculated x position *+ the initital x position*. I updated the code above, with comments behind the new parts so you can see what I changed.

### Update #3

You can see a flash file making use of the scrollbar here: http://host.undeadzone.net/scrollBarTest.swf

To reproduce issue #1, do the following:

1. grab the handle with the mouse and slowly drag the slider down, one notices that the mouse position relative to the slider stays constant. (if you clicked at the top most edge of the handle to start dragging, the mouse will still be at the top most edge when the handle reaches the bottom of the screen. this is the expected behaviour, all good.
2. Now do the opposite (it doesn't matter if you release the mouse
   after doing step 1) and drag the handle upwards slowly. This time,
   **the position of the mouse relative to the handle changes**. If one initiated the drag at the top most edge of the handle and starts
   dragging up, the handle does not keep up with the mouse and the
   mouse position (relative to the handle) will be above the handle
   after dragging, even though it started the dragging within the
   handle.

The source code:
http://host.undeadzone.net/scrollBarTest.zip

Comment: What is the container supposed to be doing and why is it a MovieClip? The _moveHandle method sure looks confusing, I'd guess the problems stem from it. Isn't it just limiting the movement to the dimensions of the bar and wouldn't good ol' startDrag() accomplish the same? Anyway, log the involved values when the undesired behaviour occurs and see if they make any sense.

Comment: @null I added some extra information, please see my updated question. Also, the scroll handle seems to move up and down equally fast when scrolling, so I don't think the problem is in `_moveHandle()` - but instead in `_startDrag()`, although I can't see what I could've done wrong

Comment: Add `e.updateAfterEvent();` in `_dragHandle`; to fix 1-st issue.

Comment: @c4isgonnablow I posted an answer with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix 1-st issue add `e.updateAfterEvent`:

```
protected function _dragHandle(e:MouseEvent){
    _moveHandle(mouseY - _mousePrevPos);
    _mousePrevPos = mouseY;
    e.updateAfterEvent();
}
```

**UPDATE**

`mouseY` returns `Number` not `int`.
Replace this line:

```
protected var _mousePrevPos:int;
```

with this:

```
protected var _mousePrevPos:Number;
```

in `Scroll` class.

**UPDATE #2**

Replace

```
protected function _moveHandle(moveDifference:int){
```

with

```
protected function _moveHandle(moveDifference:Number){
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! However, the 1st issue still occurs even after adding `e.updateAfterEvent();`

Comment: @c4isgonnablow Try to increase FPS.

Comment: I tried changing it from 24fps to 30, 60, and even 120 - but it didn't help

Comment: Can you take video from screen? I haven't such issue.

Comment: Ill try to make a gif of it

Comment: GIF it's bad. Use QuickTime to capture the video.

Comment: See my updated question for a test `swf` file and its source code

Comment: @subdan I added some instructions on how to reproduce the undesired behaviour to the question via editing.

Comment: I understood your problem.

Comment: After changing `_mousePrevPos` to `Number`, the handle also moves slower when dragged down

Comment: oops, sorry, I forgot `moveDifference`. See my update.